# Convert date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I need to convert a data from this format 26/03/2017 in this format 2017-03-26, starting from picking data from a form id.

I've tried like this, but I'm lost now.. any help?

```js
var dataform = "26/03/2017";
var dataora = new Date(dataform);


var G = dataora.getDate(dataform);
var M = (dataora.getMonth(dataform) + 1);


if (G < 10)
{
 var mm = "0" + dataora.getDate(dataform);
}
else
{
 var mm = dataora.getDate(dataform);
}

if (M < 10)
{
 var gg = "0" + (dataora.getMonth(dataform) + 1);
}
else
{
 var gg = (dataora.getMonth(dataform) + 1);
}

var aa = dataora.getFullYear(dataform);

var data = aa + "-" + mm + "-" + gg;

console.log(data);
console.log("Year "+aa);
console.log("Month "+mm);
console.log("Day "+gg);
```

Output is:

```
2019-03-02

Year 2019
Month 03
Day 02
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: i suggest using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com) to convert the data format.

Comment: You are massively overthinking this. `var input = "26/03/2017".split('/'); var output = input[2]+'-'+input[1]+'-'+input[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where am I wrong?

Don't use the Date constructor (or Date.parse) to parse strings, as it's largely implementation dependent and varies across hosts. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Per Sagar V's answer, just reformat the string.

Answer (score 1):

- Split the date using `split` function with `/`.
- Reverse it using the `reverse` function
- Then Join it using the `join` function with `-`.

That's it.

```js
var date="26/03/2017";
date=date.split("/").reverse().join("-");
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Great, it worked! Thanks